# Error while connecting Zookeeper Client

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

When I try to do some heavy junit testing by increasing number of requests on Zookeeper I get following error. It seems connection gets reset. Any one has an idea to get a work around for this. Also I am using Curator interface over Zookeeper. This happens during every execution of test suite, If I remove few test cases it works properly. Can anyone advice on this.

```
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Comment: Issue resolved. Its because I was not closing client once my processing is over.

Comment: I am also getting same error, Can anybody tell me how to fix this error.